# (TwinCAT) How to check the 'Create Symbols' box in the task options (c# automation code)

Tags: c#, task, twincat

I need to create a new task using a c# code (twincat must stay opened in background, I have to not interact directly with it), and to check the Create Symbols box from the task options, so then I can access symbols by the SymbolLoaderFactory.Create method.
The part of the code which creates the task is the following:

```
ITcSysManager sysMan = Connect2Twincat(solutionPath, solutionName);
string TaskName = "Task BECKHOFF";
ITcSmTreeItem tasks = sysMan.LookupTreeItem("TIRT");
taskBKF = tasks.CreateChild(TaskName, 0, null, null);
```

Can you please tell me how to modify the "create symbols" option? Because with that code the task has that box unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

I found out how to solve it by myself, posting the answer if anyone has the same problem.
(disclaimer: I'm not a programmer, Icould say stupid things)
It is done via xml, after the creation of the task (the code I wrote in the question).

```
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
using (XmlWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("TreeItem");
    writer.WriteStartElement("TaskDef");
    string affinityString = string.Format("#x{0}", ((ulong)affinityMask).ToString("x16"));
    writer.WriteElementString("CpuAffinity", affinityString);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
task.ConsumeXml(xml);
```

...
(from the documentation - link below) ...

```
string taskXml = taskBKF.ProduceXml();
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(taskXml);
XmlNode createSymb = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("TreeItem/TaskDef/CreateSymbols");
string xml = string.Format("<TreeItem><TaskDef><CreateSymbols>true</CreateSymbols></TaskDef></TreeItem>"); 
//the "true" in the middle defines if the create symbols box will be checked or unchecked

taskBKF.ConsumeXml(xml);
```

The example base code is here: https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_automationinterface/index.html&id=3954232867334285510